# Filter rows based on a custom calculated field

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to filter the rows returned using a WHERE condition. The problem is that MySQL is not allowing me to use a custom column name in the WHERE clause. It gives a syntax error.

```
SELECT jobs.*,

        CASE
            WHEN job_status = 'submitted'           THEN ((2 * 86400) - ($mktime - job_timestamp))/86400
            WHEN job_status = 'agreement_pending'   THEN ((1 * 86400) - ($mktime - job_tstamp_agpending))/86400
            WHEN job_status = 'payment_complete'    THEN ((job_duration * 86400) - ($mktime - job_tstamp_pcomplete))/86400
            ELSE 1000000
        END AS sla

FROM jobs 
WHERE sla < 0
```

Is it possible to still filter rows out `WHERE sla < 0` condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a special extension where you can do this using the `having` clause:

```
SELECT jobs.*,

        CASE
            WHEN job_status = 'submitted'           THEN ((2 * 86400) - ($mktime - job_timestamp))/86400
            WHEN job_status = 'agreement_pending'   THEN ((1 * 86400) - ($mktime - job_tstamp_agpending))/86400
            WHEN job_status = 'payment_complete'    THEN ((job_duration * 86400) - ($mktime - job_tstamp_pcomplete))/86400
            ELSE 1000000
        END AS sla

FROM jobs 
HAVING sla < 0;
```

This is not supported in other databases.

Answer (score 1):

A valid solution for all RDBMSes uses a Derived Table:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT jobs.*,
        CASE
            WHEN job_status = 'submitted'           THEN ((2 * 86400) - ($mktime - job_timestamp))/86400
            WHEN job_status = 'agreement_pending'   THEN ((1 * 86400) - ($mktime - job_tstamp_agpending))/86400
            WHEN job_status = 'payment_complete'    THEN ((job_duration * 86400) - ($mktime - job_tstamp_pcomplete))/86400
            ELSE 1000000
        END AS sla
    FROM jobs 
  ) AS dt
WHERE sla < 0
```